# Where can I find the paper "Un théorème de compacité" by J. P. Aubin?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, compactness, bochner-spaces

Is there any source (online or book) for the paper below?

> J. P. Aubin, Un théorème de compacité, *C.R. Acad. Sc. Paris*, **256** (1963), pp. 5042–5044.

It seems this paper is the origin of the "famous" [Aubin–Lions lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubin%E2%80%93Lions_lemma).

This lemma is proved, for example, [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=ZfKPPgAACAAJ&dq=quelques+methodes+de+resolution+lions&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAGoVChMI9PDtoOuJyQIVhR6QCh1kvw7I) and [here](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Nonlinear_Evolution_Equations.html?id=k2a18LVAXUYC&redir_esc=y), but I'd like to read the original work of Aubin. However, all I got is only a brief review (from MathSciNet).

Could someone make it available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is available on Gallica (the online platform of the France National Library) [here](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4006n/f1164.item.r=.zoom).